# Zapier Action Code: Python will not run with input_data variable

Tags: python, zapier

I am using Zapier to catch a webhook and use that info for an API post. The action code runs perfectly fine with "4111111111111111" in place of Ccnum in doSale. But when I use the input_data variable and place it in doSale it errors.

Zapier Input Variable: [image: zapier input data]

Zapier Error:
[image: Zapier error]

Python code:

```
import pycurl
import urllib
import urlparse
import StringIO


class gwapi():

    def __init__(self):
        self.login= dict()
        self.order = dict()
        self.billing = dict()
        self.shipping = dict()
        self.responses = dict()

    def setLogin(self,username,password):
        self.login['password'] = password
        self.login['username'] = username

    def setOrder(self, orderid, orderdescription, tax, shipping, ponumber,ipadress):
        self.order['orderid'] = orderid;
        self.order['orderdescription'] = orderdescription
        self.order['shipping'] = '{0:.2f}'.format(float(shipping))
        self.order['ipaddress'] = ipadress
        self.order['tax'] = '{0:.2f}'.format(float(tax))
        self.order['ponumber'] = ponumber


    def setBilling(self,
            firstname,
            lastname,
            company,
            address1,
            address2,
            city,
            state,
            zip,
            country,
            phone,
            fax,
            email,
            website):
        self.billing['firstname'] = firstname
        self.billing['lastname']  = lastname
        self.billing['company']   = company
        self.billing['address1']  = address1
        self.billing['address2']  = address2
        self.billing['city']      = city
        self.billing['state']     = state
        self.billing['zip']       = zip
        self.billing['country']   = country
        self.billing['phone']     = phone
        self.billing['fax']       = fax
        self.billing['email']     = email
        self.billing['website']   = website

    def setShipping(self,firstname,
            lastname,
            company,
            address1,
            address2,
            city,
            state,
            zipcode,
            country,
            email):
        self.shipping['firstname'] = firstname
        self.shipping['lastname']  = lastname
        self.shipping['company']   = company
        self.shipping['address1']  = address1
        self.shipping['address2']  = address2
        self.shipping['city']      = city
        self.shipping['state']     = state
        self.shipping['zip']       = zipcode
        self.shipping['country']   = country
        self.shipping['email']     = email


    def doSale(self,amount, ccnumber, ccexp, cvv=''):

        query  = ""
        # Login Information

        query = query + "username=" + urllib.quote(self.login['username']) + "&"
        query += "password=" + urllib.quote(self.login['password']) + "&"
        # Sales Information
        query += "ccnumber=" + urllib.quote(ccnumber) + "&"
        query += "ccexp=" + urllib.quote(ccexp) + "&"
        query += "amount=" + urllib.quote('{0:.2f}'.format(float(amount))) + "&"
        if (cvv!=''):
            query += "cvv=" + urllib.quote(cvv) + "&"
        # Order Information
        for key,value in self.order.iteritems():
            query += key +"=" + urllib.quote(str(value)) + "&"

        # Billing Information
        for key,value in self.billing.iteritems():
            query += key +"=" + urllib.quote(str(value)) + "&"

        # Shipping Information
        for key,value in self.shipping.iteritems():
            query += key +"=" + urllib.quote(str(value)) + "&"

        query += "type=sale"
        return self.doPost(query)



    def doPost(self,query):
        responseIO = StringIO.StringIO()
        curlObj = pycurl.Curl()
        curlObj.setopt(pycurl.POST,1)
        curlObj.setopt(pycurl.CONNECTTIMEOUT,30)
        curlObj.setopt(pycurl.TIMEOUT,30)
        curlObj.setopt(pycurl.HEADER,0)
        curlObj.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYPEER,0)
        curlObj.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION,responseIO.write);

        curlObj.setopt(pycurl.URL,"https://secure.merchantonegateway.com/api/transact.php")

        curlObj.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS,query)

        curlObj.perform()

        data = responseIO.getvalue()
        temp = urlparse.parse_qs(data)
        for key,value in temp.iteritems():
            self.responses[key] = value[0]
        return self.responses['response']

# NOTE: your username and password should replace the ones below

Ccnum = input_data['Ccnum'] #this variable I would like to use in 
                            #the  gw.doSale below

gw = gwapi()
gw.setLogin("demo", "password");

gw.setBilling("John","Smith","Acme, Inc.","123 Main St","Suite 200", "Beverly Hills",
        "CA","90210","US","555-555-5555","555-555-5556","support@example.com",
        "www.example.com")

r = gw.doSale("5.00",Ccnum,"1212",'999')
print gw.responses['response']

if (int(gw.responses['response']) == 1) :
    print "Approved"
elif (int(gw.responses['response']) == 2) :
    print "Declined"
elif (int(gw.responses['response']) == 3) :
    print "Error"
```

Towards the end is where the problems are. How can I pass the variables from Zapier into the python code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team. A few things.

First, I think your issue is the one described [here](https://curl.haxx.se/mail/curlpython-2007-07/0001.html). Namely, I believe `input_data`'s values are unicode. So you'll want to call `str(input_data['Ccnum'])` instead.

Alternatively, if you want to use [Requests](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/v2.8.1/docs/user/quickstart.rst#make-a-request), it's also supported and is a lot less finicky.

**All that said**, I would be remiss if I didn't mention that everything in Zapier code steps gets logged in plain text internally. For that reason, I'd strongly recommend against putting credit card numbers, your password for this service, and any other sensitive data through a Code step. A private server that you control is a much safer option.

​Let me know if you've got any other questions!

Comment: what threw me off was that Zapier mentioned that its input_data is a string value. Thank you and thanks for the advice.

Comment: yeah. unfortunately in python, "string" is actually a pretty ambiguous value. :/